# How to create and init ".vscode" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a project in vscode, but I don't know how to initialize the ".vscode" folder in the project, creating it by HM and the ware won't initialize any file in it.

How can I do this?

[image: An empty .vscodev]

Comment: Please provide additional infomation as to what you have done so far etc.

Comment: I just create a folder in the project, but nothing in it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Normally there should be no need to initialize anything, VSCode handles this folder by itself. As soon you do something that needs to go into this folder, for example using "Preferences->Workspace Settings" or by using one of the debugger presets, it gets populated with the files.

And if you really want to add anything by creating the files by yourself and without using the GUI or the command the palette, you just create the folder and whatever file you need. There is no additional "magic" involved, just a folder with a name.

Comment: Shucks. Doesn't happen for me...

Answer (score 30):

Try to open settings.json for your workspace/directory

open command pallete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings and then go to switch to Workspace settings. Then in autosave settings, select afterDelay option.