# Why .vscode folder is generated

Tags: angular

I had `e2e` folder in my project, but today I saw that the `e2e` folder got deleted and `.vscode` folder got generated in Angular 4 application.

What is the basic use of both the folders, can we have have both in our application and how .vscode folder got created in the project and Why?

Comment: .vscode folder contains local settings for the Visual Studio Code and it's not used by angular itself

Comment: but i never created it. the e2e folder got auto deleted and .vscode folder is created with launch.json file in it.Is launch.json is used for testing too..??

Comment: .vscode folder was created by the Visual Studio Code. I suppose you've changed the launch settings of the VS Code. The e2e folder is not connected to the .vscode, and it wouldn't be removed automatically by the VS Code.

Comment: So if i am building my project(dist folder using ng build) and e2e folder is not there while building, does it affect the application?

Comment: No, e2e contains tests for the application. Check more [here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-e2e-testing-with-the-angular-cli-and-protractor)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377654/how-to-create-and-init-vscode-in-vscode

Answer (score 0):

The .vscode folder holds your project workspace settings.

[Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to understand more about VS Code settings.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my concern is How it got created and Why.

Answer (score -2):

Various actions in VS Code appear to generate the .vscode folder if its not already there (eg use of debugger, executing various extensions).